# How can we access the window messages of a property sheet like WM_CTLCOLOR?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, propertysheet

There is a callback on the property sheet structure, PFNPROPSHEETCALLBACK, but the messages are limited to PSCB_INITIALIZED, PSCB_PRECREATE and PSCB_BUTTONPRESSED. I want to handle messages like WM_CTLCOLOR but can't seem to find a way to do it. Is it possible?

My end goal is to change the color of the tab controls and the outer frame of the property sheet dialog.

Comment: The `WM_CTLCOLOR*` messages are sent to the parent of the control. In this case the parent of the tab control, presumably a dialog you implemented. Though I don't know whether a tab control supports this customization at all.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview

Answer (score 0):

> > change the color of the tab controls

If you want to customize its appearance, I suggestm you should owner draw the tab control. And you could refer to the Doc: [Owner-Drawn Tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls?redirectedfrom=MSDN#owner-drawn-tabs)

> > change the outer frame of the property sheet dialog.

If you want to change the [Themes and Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/visual-styles-overview#themes-and-visual-styles), I suggest you could try to [enable Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).

Comment: @fidel espanto Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.